# MySQL: performance of view (selecting unique products from table)

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have created the following table with information about products:

```
CREATE TABLE `AllProducts` (
 `insertionTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `shop` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `category` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(350) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(450) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `fromPrice` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `deliveryCosts` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `stock` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `deliveryTime` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `ean` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `color` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `size` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `brand` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 KEY `category` (`category`),
 KEY `nameShopInsertiontime` (`name`,`shop`,`insertionTime`),
 KEY `name` (`name`),
 KEY `catNameShopInsert` (`category`,`name`,`shop`,`insertionTime`),
 KEY `eanName` (`ean`,`name`),
 KEY `eanInsertionTime` (`ean`,`insertionTime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_c
```

I want to create a view that selects all unique products from that table (a 'prototype product' view). Some products in my table have an EAN number, but not all. If there is an EAN number available I want to use that as a productId. If it is not available I want to hash the name (in lowercase) and use that as a productId.

I have created the following view which uses a union all to distinct between the situations described above. It works, but takes 4.3 seconds to complete (on 200.000 rows). This is too slow.

```
select 
max(`ap`.`name`) AS `name`,
max(`ap`.`description`) AS `description`,
min(`ap`.`price`) AS `price`,
max(`ap`.`image`) AS `image`,
`ap`.`ean` AS `ean`,
max(`ap`.`color`) AS `color`,
max(`ap`.`size`) AS `size`,
max(`ap`.`brand`) AS `brand`,
`ap`.`ean` AS `productId` 
from `AllProducts` `ap` 
where (not((`ap`.`ean` like ''))) 
group by `ap`.`ean` 

union all 

select 
`ap`.`name` AS `name`,
max(`ap`.`description`) AS `description`,
min(`ap`.`price`) AS `price`,
max(`ap`.`image`) AS `image`,
'' AS `ean`,
max(`ap`.`color`) AS `color`,
max(`ap`.`size`) AS `size`,
max(`ap`.`brand`) AS `brand`,
md5(lcase(`ap`.`name`)) AS `productId` 
from `AllProducts` `ap` 
where (`ap`.`ean` = '') 
group by `ap`.`name` order by NULL
```

If there are multiple products available it takes the longest/shortest available description (or color/size/whatever). I do not necessarily need the longest or shortest value, but just any value.

My questions: what can I do to increase the performance of this view?

---

using Mani's comments I switched to the following situation, which indeed is quite fast.

```
select 
`ap`.`name` AS `name`,
`ap`.`description` AS `description`,
a.category,
`ap`.`price` AS `price`,
`ap`.`image` AS `image`,
`ap`.`ean` AS `ean`,
`ap`.`color` AS `color`,
`ap`.`size` AS `size`,
`ap`.`brand` AS `brand`,
case when ap.ean not like '' then ap.ean else md5(lcase(ap.name)) end as productId
from `AllProducts` `ap`
```

This view is quite fast. However, I still need to select the unique productIds from this new view - including a name, description, category and so on (view is called AllProductsView). I tried the following, which results in a slower query than the original (6.5 seconds):

```
select max(`apv`.`name`) AS `name`,
max(`apv`.`description`) AS  `description`,
max(`apv`.`category`) AS `category`,
min(`apv`.`price`) AS `price`,
max(`apv`.`image`) AS `image`,
max(`apv`.`color`) AS `color`,
max(`apv`.`size`) AS `size`,
max(`apv`.`brand`) AS `brand`,
`apv`.`productId` AS `productId` 
from `AllProductsView` `apv` 
group by `apv`.`productId`
```

Anyone has suggestions how to speed up this query?

Answer (score 0):

dint hit the table twice. Use ifnull function.

ifnull(`ap`.`ean`, md5(lcase(`ap`.`name`))) as productID

Comment: Then go for (case when then end)

Comment: Thanks; but still not quite there yet; I still have to select the unique productIds. I placed some extra information in the question; would you mind taking a look at this?